# Include additional fields when using COUNT() with JOINed tables?

Tags: sql, join, count

I'm going to learn SQL, and having troubes with one of the excercises. "Get the number of customers each employee is responsible for" (I hope the translation is OK). I figured out following:

```
SELECT emp.EmployeeId, COUNT(cus.SupportRepId) AS Customers
FROM Employee AS emp JOIN Customer AS cus 
ON cus.SupportRepId = emp.EmployeeId
GROUP BY emp.EmployeeId
```

The result is correct so far:

```
EmployeeId      Customers
-------------------------
3               21
4               20
...             ...
```

Now I thought it would be nice to addional employee's data in the result too (e.g. JobTitle from the table 'Employee'), but this doesn't seems to work:

```
SELECT emp.EmployeeId, emp.JobTitle, COUNT(cus.SupportRepId) AS Customers
FROM Employee AS emp JOIN Customer AS cus 
ON cus.SupportRepId = emp.EmployeeId
GROUP BY emp.EmployeeId
```

I don't understand why. What should I have to in order to get the expected result:

```
EmployeeId      JobTitle              Customers
------------------------------------------------
3               Key Account Manager   21
4               Business Area Manager 20
...             ...
```

I hope you can help. Have much thanks in before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw it in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.JobTitle, COUNT(c.SupportRepId) AS Customers
FROM Employee e JOIN
     Customer c 
     ON c.SupportRepId = e.EmployeeId
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId, e.JobTitle;
```

Alternatively, you can use a correlated subquery or aggregate before joining:

```
SELECT e.*, c.Customers
FROM Employee e JOIN
     (SELECT c.SupportRepId, COUNT(c.SupportRepId) AS Customers
      FROM Customer c 
      GROUP BY c.SupportRepId
     ) c
     ON c.SupportRepId = e.EmployeeId;
```